# Numpy array broadcasting with vector parameters

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to do array broadcasting in numpy with parameters that are vectors?

For example, I know that I can do this

```
def bernoulli_fraction_to_logodds(fraction):
    if fraction == 1.0:
        return inf
    return log(fraction / (1 - fraction))
bernoulli_fraction_to_logodds = numpy.frompyfunc(bernoulli_fraction_to_logodds, 1, 1)
```

and have it work with the whole array.  What if I have a function that take a 2-element vector and returns a 2-element vector.  Can I pass it an array of 2-element vectors?  E.g.,

```
def beta_ml_fraction(beta):
    a = beta[0]
    b = beta[1]
    return a / (a + b)
beta_ml_fraction = numpy.frompyfunc(beta_ml_fraction, 1, 1)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  Is there a similar function to from_py_func that works.  I can hack around this when they are 2-element vectors, but what about when they are n-element vectors?

Thus, input of `(2,3)` should give `0.4`, but input of `[[2,3], [3,3]]` should give `[0.4, 0.5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with bidimensional vector array I like to keep the x and y components as the first index. For this I make heavy use of the transpose()

```
def beta_ml_fraction(beta):
        a = beta[0]
        b = beta[1]
   return a / (a + b)

arr=np.array([(2,3),(3,3)],dtype=np.float) 
print(beta_ml_fraction(arr.transpose()))
# [ 0.4  0.5]
```

the advantage of this approach is that handling multidimensional array of bi-dimensional vector becomes easiear.

```
x = np.arange(18,dtype=np.float).reshape(2,3,3)
print(x)
#array([[[  0.,   1.,   2.],
#        [  3.,   4.,   5.],
#        [  6.,   7.,   8.]],
#
#       [[  9.,  10.,  11.],
#        [ 12.,  13.,  14.],
#        [ 15.,  16.,  17.]]])
print(beta_ml_fraction(x))
#array([[ 0.        ,  0.09090909,  0.15384615],
#       [ 0.2       ,  0.23529412,  0.26315789],
#       [ 0.28571429,  0.30434783,  0.32      ]])
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `frompyfunc` can do this, though I could be wrong.

Regarding `np.vectorize` [A. M. Archibald wrote](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg00587.html):

> In fact, anything that goes through
>   python code for the "combine two
>   scalars" will be slow. The slowness of
>   looping in python is not because
>   python's looping constructs are slow,
>   it's because executing python code is
>   slow. So vectorize is kind of a cheat
>   - it doesn't actually run fast, but it is convenient.

So `np.frompyfunc` (and `np.vectorize`) are just syntactic sugar -- they don't make Python functions run any faster.
After realizing that, my interest in `frompyfunc` flagged (to near zero).

There is nothing unreadable about a Python loop, so either use one explicitly,
or rewrite the function to truly leverage numpy (by writing truly vectorized equations).

```
import numpy as np

def beta_ml_fraction(beta):    
    a = beta[:,0]
    b = beta[:,1]
    return a / (a + b)


arr=np.array([(2,3)],dtype=np.float)
print(beta_ml_fraction(arr))
# [ 0.4]

arr=np.array([(2,3),(3,3)],dtype=np.float)
print(beta_ml_fraction(arr))
# [ 0.4  0.5]
```